# Calculate integral of function using Monte Carlo method ranging from 3 to 10

Tags: function, montecarlo, integral

I am trying to calculate integral of function f(x) = log(2 + sin(e^x)) in interval of between 3 and 10. I have to use the Monte Carlo method which approximates the result by multiplying function (f(x) mean by the interval of 7 (or 10 - 3 in this case).

using scipy.integrate.quad the answer comes to 
4.375668121469594

My code:

```
import scipy.stats as sps
x = sps.uniform.rvs(size=1000)
f = np.log(2 + np.sin(np.exp(x)))

def Monte_Carlo (f, a, b):
    h = (b-a)
    result = h * np.mean(f)
    return result
```

I guess what needs to happen is for f to loop through all instances of x and store results in a list

Comment: What did you try? Show us the code